# Regularity of eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint differential operator in Gilbarg-Trudinger

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth domain,
$Lu = D_i \left( a^{ij} (x) D_ju \right)$, and two constants
$\lambda, \Lambda > 0$. Suppose the coefficient $a$ is measurable,
symmetric, and satisfies
$$
a^{ij} \xi_i \xi_j \ge \lambda \vert{\xi} \vert^2 \quad  \text{ and} \quad
\sum_{i,j}^{} \vert{a^{ij}(x)}\vert \le \Lambda^2,
$$
for all $x \in \Omega, \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$. **However, $a$ can be discontinuous and not belong to any $VMO$ or $BMO$ spaces.**

Let $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ be a weak solution of $Lu = g$ for
$g \in L^{q/2},~ q > n$.  Denote by
$\mathtt{data} = (\lambda,\Lambda,n,q)$. Then Theorem 8.15 in
Gilbarg-Trudinger, *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second
Order*, says that
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \le C (\mathtt{data}) \left( \Vert u \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)} + \Vert g \Vert_{L^{q/2}(\Omega)} \right),
$$
and Theorem 8.24 in the same book says that for any $\Omega' \subset
\Omega$,
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{C^{\alpha} \left( \Omega' \right)} \le K (\mathtt{data}, \text{dist}(\Omega',\Omega)) \left( \Vert u
\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)} + \Vert g \Vert_{L^{q/2}(\Omega)}\right).
$$

On page 214, after Theorem 8.37, the authors claim that solutions $w
\in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$
of the eigenvalue problem
$$
Lw + \sigma w = 0,
$$
belong to $L^{\infty} (\Omega) \cap C^{\alpha}(\Omega)$, thanks to the
above theorems 8.15 and 8.24.

**My question:**  If $2 \le n \le 4$, then by
Sobolev embedding, we have $w \in W^{1,2}_0 \hookrightarrow L^{q/2}$
for some $q > n$. Therefore, we can apply theorems 8.15 and 8.24. What
about the case $n \ge 5$?

Any insights or references are appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [Luigi Orsina's Lecture Notes](https://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/orsina/AS1213/AS1213.pdf). They are beautifully written, and page 24 you will read Stampacchia's approach, which is (in my view) more elegant than Moser iterations and gives you the result you need in a jiffy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I ignore the condition of $a_{ij}$, but there is a Moser's iteration for $-\Delta u + V(x)u=0$. For instance, see Struwe's Variational Methods Appendix B lemma B.3. And I think this iteration doesn't need the continuous of $a$.

More precisely, integral the equation $Lu+cu=0$ by $u\min\{|u|^{2s}, M^2\}\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, then we have
$$\int a^{ij}u_i u_j \min\{|u|^{2s}, M^2\} +\frac{s}{2}\int _{|u|^s\leq M} a^{ij} (|u|^2)_i (|u|^2)_j|u|^{2s-2}\leq c\int |u|^2\min\{|u|^{2s},M^2\}.$$
For $s$ small enough such that $u\in L^{2+2s}(\Omega)$ we have
$$\int a^{ij}u_i u_j \min\{|u|^{2s}, M^2\} \text{ is bounded uniformly with} ~M.$$
Hence let $M\to \infty$, we have
$$\int |D|u|^{s+1}|^2<\infty,$$
which means, by Sobolev embedding, $u\in L^{\frac{(2s+2)n}{n-2}}(\Omega)$. By iteration, you can obtain that $u\in L^{q}(\Omega)$ for all $q>1$.